# How to add subsubsubsection to acm conference template

Tags: sectioning, sections-paragraphs, acm, acmart

I am using ACM conference template. I can not add `\subsubsubsection` and the `\par` does not add number. How can I overcome this issue? Can you please help me add another level section?

Here is my sample:

```
\documentclass[sigconf, anonymous]{acmart}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array, makecell} 

\begin{document}

\title{Title}

\begin{abstract}
Abstract  
\end{abstract}

\maketitle

\section{This is a Section} Some text here.
\subsection{This is a Subsection} Some text here. 
\subsubsection{This is a subsubsection} Text here.
\par{This is par. But I need a third level section as 1.1.1.1}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You don't want to use `\par` but `\paragraph`. It depends on the counter `secnumdepth` whether a paragraph is numbered. It becomes numbered for `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}` or greater. Also to make that work with `acmart` you'd have to define an indentation width for a paragraph in the ToC, this can be done with: `\expandafter\newcommand\csname r@tocindent4\endcsname{4in}`

Comment: In general if you want to contribute that document, I don't know whether it is a good idea to change the template in such a way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turning my comment into an answer:

You can control how many sectioning commands get numbered with the `secnumdepth` counter. If this is set to `4` or greater `\paragraph` will produce a number. Note however that a `\paragraph` by default is not a heading but gets printed on the same line as the start of that paragraph.

The command `\par` is the same as a blank line in TeX, meaning it ends the previous paragraph (text block not sectioning layer).

```
\documentclass[sigconf, anonymous]{acmart}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array, makecell} 

\expandafter\newcommand\csname r@tocindent4\endcsname{4in}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}

\begin{document}

\title{Title}

\begin{abstract}
Abstract  
\end{abstract}

\maketitle

\section{This is a Section} Some text here.
\subsection{This is a Subsection} Some text here. 
\subsubsection{This is a subsubsection} Text here.
\paragraph{This is par. But I need a third level section as 1.1.1.1}

\end{document}
```